# gtkmm/button.h no such file or directory

Tags: codelite

Whenever i try to run my code this error "gtkmm/button.h no such file or directory" pop up in the console i don't know what is this error and this page also pops up every time. This is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class bubble{
private:
    arr[5];
public:
    void getdata();
    void sort();
    void display();
};
void bubble::getdata(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        cout<<"enter the element in the array";
        cin>>""<<arr[i];
    }
}
void bubble::sort(){
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=4;j++)
        {
            temp=arr[j];
            arr[j]=arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
void bubble::display(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        cout<<"after sorting the array intto bubble sort: "<<arr[i];
    }
}
int main(){
    bubble b;
    b.getdata();
    b.sort();
    b.display();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bubble sorting program doesn't seem to use any GTKMM APIs. It's a pure console program, not a GUI application.

The popup error could be because of your IDE codelite configuration mess up. I don't use codelite so I cannot really know for sure.

Have you tried compiling your C++ program and running it on cmd or terminal prompt?

Comment: sir i did reinstalled my codelite and then it worked smoothly.

Comment: OK :) You could add your own answer here and mark it as done. Might need 2-3 days before you can mark your own answer. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question sir. I'm glad you cared to answer my question.